# How do I configure messaging in jboss eap 7 server?

Tags: java, jboss

I am trying to configure a jboss eap 7.0 server. But there is something wrong with the messaging configuration part. When I start the server I get the following error:

```
   ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot 
    Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("subsystem" => "messaging-activemq"),
    ("server" => "default")
]) - failure description: {
"WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.messaging-activemq.default is missing [jboss.http-upgrade-registry.messaging, jboss.http-upgrade-registry.messaging-throughput]"],
"WFLYCTL0288: One or more services were unable to start due to one or more indirect dependencies not being available." => {
    "Services that were unable to start:" => ["jboss.messaging-activemq.default.jms.manager"],
    "Services that may be the cause:" => [
        "jboss.http-upgrade-registry.messaging",
        "jboss.http-upgrade-registry.messaging-throughput",
        "jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.jdbc.SVIL-STJU"
    ]
}
}
```

I want to note that I have added the messaging extension:

`<extension module="org.wildfly.extension.messaging-activemq"/>`

I searched for a solution but didn't find any.

Comment: Please use standlaone-full.xml which has all the things you need for messaging. that way you dont need to add anything... 
See this  video which has useful inputs https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ef0HFbyaHFs